# Can't run command php artisan migrate for laravel 5

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am using "larvel/framework": 5, I try to migrate but it gives an error like below

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Acc?s refus? pour l'utilisateur: 'homestead'@'@local
  host' (mot de passe: OUI)
```

My configuration in laravel\config\database.php:

```
'mysql' => [

            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'read-it-later'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your environment configurations.

Find the file named as `.env` from your project root directory, and set your database configurations there.

**OR**

Just rename `.env` file as `.env.example`

**OR**

Remove `env()` method and just set your settings directly in `database.php` file.

> This error occurred because your database configuration uses the `.env` which ultimately point to `homestead` database.

Note:

> Whenever you use `env()` method, Laravel looks for the variable in `.env` file. If the variable not found then only it takes the second parameter value from `evn()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a server along like in **cmd** you have

> php artisan serve

running, so you have to stop that just by pressing **CTRL+C** and then restart by the command

> php artisan serve

again. I hope It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is using .env file so change the .env file or change in the database.php file without env()

for example replace this line : 'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), by this line 'host'      => 'localhost' and this line 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your data base name'),  by this line 'database'  => 'your data base', etc...